# Orion Federation Security

Tags: fiware-orion

Let's suppose a scenario where we have two Orions deployed in different cloud infrastructures. These Orions are behind a PEP (Wilma) each, with no posibilty of accesing them without autentication.

- Would it be possible to federate these Orions through the PEP?
- If the Orion2 (O2) is the context provider of Orion1 (O1) when an O1 user request a queryContext to O1 will the access token propagate to O2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the access token in `x-auth-header` is propagated in forwarded requests so the scenario you propose (named ["pull" federation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/federation/index.html)) should work.

**EDIT**: is the CB receiving the propagated request uses a PEP governed by the same security framework of the sending CB (in other words, the PEP of both CBs share the same IDM/AC instance) then federation is automatic. If the CBs doesn't share the same IDM/AC instance then you need some piece in the middle (a proxy) able to translate the `x-auth-header` valid in the sending CB to a `x-auth-token` valid in the receiving CB (the proxy should interact with the IDM governing the receiving CB).

Comment: What hapen if the token expires every x minutes, is there any internal mechanism to renew it?

Comment: As far as I know, the IDM API includes methods to renew a token. You should ask it as a separate question so IDM experts can answer properly, please. Thanks!

Comment: I am going to asq but i bet that they will tell me that i should do the question to Orion experts. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Hint: do the question independently of Orion, without mentioning it. I mean, something like "How I can renew a token in IDM using an existing token?"

Comment: For normal applications it is pretty easy, the goal is to use security between federated orions.

Comment: I misunderstand the question derived in the comments, sorry... (I thought you asked specifically how to renew an IDM token). I have edited my answer post to provide some extra information I hope can be useful about federating CBs in security aware scenarios.